# Increasing Youtube API V3 quota

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

When you try and apply for a higher quota limit right now it says:

> We Are Not Approving Quota Requests

Does that mean there is no way for me to pay to increase my quota limit? What if I build an app that ends up acquiring millions of users?

Answer (score 4):

Correct; there is currently no way to increase the quota. While the current limits are very generous, you're right in that, eventually, an incredibly successful app might start bumping up against that.

The best advice is to craft your API calls carefully now (for example, make use of the 'fields' parameter to only get back what you need and hence lessen the cost of each call), and then worry about API limits when it becomes a problem.